# PHP exec() wrong output

Tags: php

I am executing an AJAX request using jQuery as such:

```
$.get({
          url: 'run_program.php',
          data: 'action=run&number=' + $('#number').val(),
          success: function (j) {
            alert(j);
          }
```

runprogram.php is as such:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
    run($_GET['number']);
}

function run($number) {
    echo shell_exec('program.exe $number');
}
?>
```

The response I get from the server is always 0. I am running this locally by the way, so there are no security problems. The program is simply coded to square the number passed in as input. It works perfectly fine in cmd. When I echo $number, it correctly gives the value that I passed in using jQuery. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: ouch - `runprogram.php?number=0;cat%20/etc/passwd`

Comment: You're passing literally `program.exe $number` to the shell. You need to change the single quotes to double quotes: `"program.exe $number"` or move the variable outside the string: `'program.exe '.$number`

Comment: @Alnitak, pretty much what I was about to say. Scary how many times we find this kind of code on Stack Overflow.

Comment: use double quotes with shell_exec() arguments, otherwise $number is not expanded by PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would be your line

```
echo shell_exec('program.exe $number');
```

in that this will actually call program.exe with "$number" as text as a value. You need to use double quotes eg

```
echo shell_exec("program.exe $number");
```

Comment: I'm not upvoting an answer that doesn't fix the massive security problem at the same time...

Comment: @Alnitak why not? This answers the question perfectly.  The comments above highlight the security issue.

Comment: @JonTaylor because it would be irresponsible, and also indicates that the poster is themselves unaware of the security problem.

Comment: I am aware of the security problem, I just wanted to know what was wrong and this answers it perfectly.

Comment: *"I am running this locally by the way, so there are no security problems."* - if you're not exposing the software to the public and only using it yourself, there's no real reason to patch every security hole. It should be a safe bet that the OP isn't going to hack himself.

Comment: It is not irresponsible at all.  While I agree that people need to learn of such security issues, This answer perfectly answers the question asked.  The fact the guy has other security concerns is not the point.

Comment: @Juhana I don't think that was in the original text of the question.

Comment: @Alnitak, the other thing is, if its running on windows (possibly is given hes said program.exe) the ; .. attack doesnt work.

Comment: @BugFinder regardless, we wouldn't some other newbie to come along and find this answer and not have the security risks pointed out.

Comment: @Alnitak the bugs were pointed out in your first comment on the OP, theres no need to have to point them out in order to have your answer voted up when actually your answer, as weve already said multiple times, answer the question asked.

Comment: @Alnitak, I meant in general, you posted a comment earlier which pointed out the security concerns, however as it is not relevant to the actual question asked this should not be the basis of refusing to upvote someones answer.

Comment: @Alnitak, I appreciate that you wish to make it very visible that there is a security risk, but the OP did mention it in his question. I appreciate you dont wish to upvote my answer, I can live with that, thats your decision.